# $this->request->is('ajax') always false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have the code in my view but on sending to my controller action via ajax(as shown in the last part of the add.ctp)

```
//add.ctp
 <?php
  echo $this->Form->create('Poll',array('action' => 'index'));
  echo $this->Form->input('one', array('id'=>'name'));
  echo $this->Form->input('two', array('id'=>'email'));
  echo $this->Form->input('three', array('id'=>'message'));
  echo $this->Form->input('four', array('id'=>'four'));


 echo $this->Js->submit('Send', array('id' => 'btn'), array(
 'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
 'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
 'update'=>'#success'
  )); 
  echo $this->Form->end();
  ?>

<div id="sending" style="display: none; background-color: lightgreen;">Sending...</div>
<script>



 $('#btn').click(function(event) {

 form = $("#PollIndexForm").serialize();

  // console.log(form);
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'pollsController/index';,
   data: form,

   success: function(data){
      //
   }

 });

 event.preventDefault();
// return false;  //stop the actual form post !important!

});

</script>
```

on getting to my controller, I made an `isAjax` request test and if failed

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function index(){ 
$this->autoRender = false;

      if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
    echo debug('Ajax call');

       }
     if(!empty($this->data)){
       echo debug('not empty');
      }
}
```

I get 'not empty' every time i tried to run this and `$this->request->is('ajax')` is always false
My version of cakephp is 2.3 and I have tried `$this->request->is('ajax')` and all that. 
I'll appreciate if someone can point out what I am missing out

Comment: Could you try to open developer console or firebug or some debugging tool and copy the request headers? Also note your url `pollsController` is very strange, try just **polls** I suspect you are being redirected

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending with your AJAX call the right headers?

```
{ 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
```

If you are using `jQuery`, you can use:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' }
})
```

You can check it in `Chrome developer tools` under the network tab, where you must select your request.

and here is [the documentation for ajaxSetup()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)

**EDIT:**

You can put it here:

```
<script>
$('#btn').click(function(event) {
    form = $("#PollIndexForm").serialize();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' }
    })
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'pollsController/index';,
        data: form,
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    // return false;  //stop the actual form post !important!
});
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery sends that by default, no need to set it.

Comment: As a newbie,I've never heard of this before what file am I going to put this? I am using cakephp framework

Comment: @ceejayoz not true, depends on version, system, server, etc. For example I MUST do it this way...

Comment: @user3340752 just place it anywhere before your AJAX call

Comment: Still not fixed after doing that

Comment: Have you checked your ajax call in dev tools/fire bug? what does it say?

Comment: @KamilMaraz It wouldn't depend on the server at all, and it's been in jQuery versions at least six years. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2356 If you're not getting it on a jQuery AJAX request, it's **a bug**.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have

```
if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
```

Try to make the condition this way:

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {

}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html?highlight=isajax#requesthandlercomponent

> RequestHandlerComponent: Many of RequestHandlerComponent’s methods are
>   just proxies for CakeRequest methods. The following methods have been
>   deprecated and will be removed in future versions: isSsl() isAjax()
>   isPost() isPut() isFlash() isDelete() getReferer()getClientIp()

Comment: I just did that. same result